# class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist. Application.properties is not accessable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

In my SpringBoot application. Somehow my appication.properties file is not getting read during execution. I am getting below error again n again.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Below is what I have tried so far, but I didn't get success.

1- In my config class, I added this:

```
@PropertySource(value="classpath:/application.properties")
public class StudentConfig {
```

2- In My config class, I added this

```
@Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer location = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        location.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        location.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return location;
    }
```

3- I checked my properties file is inside Resources folder and still it is not picking the file.

Below is my error log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.student.main.StudentBackendApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.student.main.StudentBackendApplication.main(StudentBackendApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:159) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:99) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:59) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:67) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:37) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:462) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:279) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:303) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: where did you place the file?, If it is in the classpath, you shouldn't have any problem

Comment: It is inside Resource folder.This is path - ../src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: You are using spring boot remove the `@PropertySource` and `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. Spring Boot will load if for you automatically. You are working around the framework instead of with it.

Comment: @M.Deinum When I removed above annotation and method. I am getting this error. Error creating bean with name 'studentConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'db.driver' in value "${db.driver}"

Comment: Which also looks like you are working around Spring Boot (configuring your own DB instead of using the Spring Boot provided one). Make sure it is actually present in the `application.properties` but I would suggest using the `spring.datasource.*` properties and remove your own `DataSource` config (as Spring Boot does that for you).

Comment: I understand what you are saying here. However can't we do this in the way I am trying. I meant what if I want to configure it in this way. All the details are there in application.properties then why it is not picking it up.

Answer (score 2):

If using project manager as Maven, take care to correctly define the packaging entry as jar/war instead of pom in the module's pom.xml

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```